# Android using multiple threadpoolexecutors

Tags: android, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

Hey here's an interesting question. I am using in my Android project, lots of sql operations with sqlite. For this matter, I am using thread pool in order of reusing the existing resources. The thread pool look's like this:

```
final int NUMBER_OF_CORES = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor= new ThreadPoolExecutor(NUMBER_OF_CORES*2,NUMBER_OF_CORES*2,1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(12,true),new PriorityThreadFactory(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND),new RejectedThread(context));



public class PriorityThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {

    private final int mThreadPriority;

    public PriorityThreadFactory(int threadPriority) {
        mThreadPriority = threadPriority;
    }

    @Override
    public Thread newThread(final Runnable runnable) {
        Runnable wrapperRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(mThreadPriority);
                } catch (Throwable t) {

                }
                runnable.run();
            }
        };
        return new Thread(wrapperRunnable);
    }

    }




public class RejectedThread implements RejectedExecutionHandler {

    MyLogger myLogger;

    public RejectedThread(Context context) {
        this.myLogger=new MyLogger(RejectedThread.class.getSimpleName(), context);
    }

    @Override
    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable worker, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
        this.myLogger.info("Execution rejected for: "+worker.toString());
    }
}
```

And also I am creating a new Runnable for every CRUD (Create-Read-Update-Delete) operation that I make in the database (being executed by the thread pool above). Here is the questions, beside the threadpool for sql operations, I would need one more thread pool for executing logger operations, to log system behavior for the rest of my functions that I make. Is there a way to prevent any crush/(insufficient resources) because I am using two or more thread pool executors (allocated separated, using in different purposes and **never** executing a thread pool executor on another thread pool executor) ?

Comment: This all seems overkill. Why do you need thread pool for logger operations? Also why cant you use existing executor from AsyncTask class? Do you have any issues with it?

Comment: won't all `CRUD` operations be synchronised anyway meaining running pools of threads isn't really an advantage?

Comment: [Okas] All of those logs are sent to a service, so this operation is always in the background. I am trying to accomplish something like: Firebase Crash Reporting ( https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ ) but using my very one personal server and with less functionalities.

Comment: [Mark Keen] i consider that i have a big advance, because all the crud operations (for me) are being done where I always receive a push notification. Based on the message that I receive, my app knows what operation to perform, and in this way my ui thread is free.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that in general your idea is very good, but your implementation is a bit inefficient.

Try to answer these questions to yourself:

- Why do you need two thread pools?
- Do you REALLY need two thread pools?
- Why do you set CORE size to NUMBER_OF_CORES*2?
- Why do you set MAX size to NUMBER_OF_CORES*2?
- Do you REALLY need to overwrite threads priorities?

In my experience, none of the above complications are really necessary.

For example, in all my apps I use a single instance of `BackgroundThreadPoster` class in order to offload work to background threads. The class is very simple:

```
/**
 * A single instance of this class should be used whenever we need to post anything to a (random) background thread.
 */
public class BackgroundThreadPoster {

    ExecutorService mExecutorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    public void post(Runnable runnable) {
        mExecutorService.execute(runnable);
    }
}
```

Default pre-configured implementation returned by `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` works like magic and I've never encountered any need to customize its parameters.

A full tutorial application that uses this approach can be found here: https://github.com/techyourchance/android_mvc_tutorial

Maybe this can work for you too?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!